# Bootstrap menu dropdown closes when mouse goes over Facebook login button in IE

Tags: css, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap on a website for the first time and have run into an issue with IE (tested in version 11).

I have a login form in a dropdown menu and below the form I have a Facebook login button. No problem in FF & Chrome, but IE (as usual) is acting strange. When the mouse goes over the Facebook login button, the dropdown suddenly closes.

Here's the website: http://www.pricewombat.com/

Steps to replicate:

1. Go to the website in IE
2. Hover over Sign In to open the dropdown
3. Move mouse over the Facebook login button
4. Feel sorry for IE

What might be causing the issue, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I believe that Irvin Zhan is right when he assumes that the `iframe` causes the problem in IE. So when you have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button/ there is an alternative to the iframe, using just HTML(5). Can you use this method?

Comment: @Netsurfer The code I'm using is from that page. I believe what happens is that facebook parses the page body and then dynamically inserts the iframe. Unless I'm missing something..

Comment: Yes, seems so! BTW: It's a bit hard to see, as your hover effect (the drop-down) does not work without JS. But OK, so you cannot avoid the appearance of the `iframe`. I'll think about a possible solution ...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's an old "bug" which already exists at least as of IE 7.
The problem is, that IE looses the :hover state, when there is an iframe inside the hovered element.

I set up a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9s4KZ/9/) which worked for me (tested with IE 11 and changed mode via developer tools), but I had to choose jQuery version 1.9.1 as 1.10.x doesn't work!

Explanation: When the `li` element has `mouseenter` event (so it is hovered), and also when the `iframe` is hovered, an additional class name is added to the `li`. And it is removed when the `mouseleave` event occurs.

The Javascript code is not that "elegant", but should only demonstrate the needed concept. ;-)

Comment: this is great!  was there any particular reason why JQuery 1.10.x didn't work?

Comment: @IrvinZhan It throws an error, but I didn't investigate it further. Normally it shouldn't make a big difference if you use 1.9.x or 1.10.x!

Comment: Your solution works very well, and with jQuery 1.11.0 as well! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it may be because of the way IE handles hovering over iframes.  When you hover over the Facebook "Sign In" iframe, IE thinks that you are no longer hovering over the dropdown.  One possible solution is adding a hover state using JQuery:

```
$('.fb-login-button').hover(function(){
      $('.dropdown').mouseover();
});
```

If you are using Modernizr, you can wrap this in a nice if statement to make it so that this will only execute for IE.

Unfortunately, I do not have access to IE right now so I am unable to test this out, but this is my best guess.  Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Tried, but no cigar. Thanks for the idea, though. +1